# Send a notification message to vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, notifications

I'm developing a vb.net windows application and I want some my users will be notified when a new event occurs.(for example: update a field in table, or add a new row in a table) This notification should have same UI as my other vb forms.( I'd like to show it on a seperate form, not any windows messageboxes)

I don't know the easiest solution for the problem.

Thanks in advance.

-Edited-

The 'notification' i'm trying to explain is something like facebook. For example: While surfing facebook, a friend comments on a status and there is a notification on the top left corner of the page. I'm trying to develop this windows application that uses live data when a record in sql is added, deleted or edited. This application is being run concurrently in many computers(so far only 2) and when 1 user modifies a record the other user will be notified through this 'notification pop-up".

And yes using windows forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Fabian's answer.

In the database you should have a boolean, False = unread and True = read "notification".

You can make a linq query which gets all the False notifications. To which you edit the  numbers, colors and UI.

```
Dim getUnread = (From rec In db.Notifications
                Where rec.messageBoolean = False
                Select rec).toList()
'number of notifications
dim numberOfNotifications as Integer = getUnread.count

If numberOfNotifications >0 Then 
   labalNotify.text = numberOfNotifications.tostring()
   'change colors, add icons, make the world go round.

  End If
```

I think you get the picture

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're using Winforms?

The steps are:

- Make a new form
- When the event occurs (i.e. in your event handler), use:

  ```
  var myForm = new NotificationForm();
  NotificationForm.Show();
  ```

See also [To show a new Form on click of a button in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553235/to-show-a-new-form-on-click-of-a-button-in-c-sharp)

If you want the notification to appear in an unobtrusive fashion, add a `Label` somewhere on the form and update the `Label.Text` property.

To check for a change in SQL database records, you'd want to look at using a web service (if the application needs to be scalable) or, to access a SQL Server database directly, take a look at the [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) class.

Best of luck.