# How Do I show Notification when Application is closed Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I'm Java Developer and new to Vb.net,I using Win form for developing Windows Application
and my application is showing the notification for new changes in database(i.e new row added)
So how can i achieve this in Vb.net.? should I use Services for it(but as i read, services can not interact with UI) I don't know what to use for getting data in background and show update in notification when my application is in background/close.

Lots of thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be notified about any changes or updates that happen to the database even if your win app is closed ?

Comment: yes. means I want the app is sync to server after specific time and it will check for update if update available then need to show the notification popup. even application closed. How could we achieve it in VB.net

Comment: If app is closed, something else must be running. The service cannot interact with UI but it can start it. And you could check at start up if some changes have been made to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at something like this:

[Send a notification message to vb.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285808/send-a-notification-message-to-vb-net-application)

[Create a System Tray Application in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75822/Create-a-System-Tray-Application-in-VB-NET)
Here you could allow the tray to display a notification in case 2 or more users are using your app so that they can be notified. However, you should consider database centralization as mentioned [**here**](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=5601)

Also you can see [Implementing SQL Notification](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/4264-implementing-sql-notification.aspx)