# Different Form on each click c#

Tags: c#

How to create and display a new form each time I Click a button (in my base form which is MDI Container) in C#. Each time I click button a new child form should open.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/How–to-ask) we debug code not generate it, google will give you most answers you need

Answer (score 0):

[Google is your friend!](https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20open%20new%20form%20on%20button%20click)

Here's some examples:

- [How to open the second form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718183/how-to-open-the-second-form)
- [To show a new Form on click of a button in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553235/to-show-a-new-form-on-click-of-a-button-in-c-sharp)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws1btzy8(v=vs.90).aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Scenario is on each click a new form shows up or it should be created.  My Parent form is MDI Container . i want that each time i click the button in my parent form it should open a new form. Code behind button is to show a form when its clicked.